# Function/macro to add the same menu/footer on all pages

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to define a function / macro that expand to HTML when inserted on my page. I want to use this for my footer and my menu, which are the same on every page, without having to repeat it on every page. Because when something is changed all pages have to be updated manually...

This is for my personal web site (10-15 pages) so I having fun by using pure HTML/CSS, no server side coding.

As an example I want my footer HTML below to appear on every page:

```
<footer id="footer">
    <p>(c) Mattias Lindberg, 2011-2014</p>
</footer>
```

And all I want to do is add something similar to the below:

```
<footer id="footer" />
```

Which should then expand to the HTML above.

How do I do that using HTML/CSS/jQuery or other client-side technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't specified `PHP` in your tag list, here is the `Jquery` code.

The HTML page: `footer.html`.

```
<footer>
<p>(c) Mattias Lindberg, 2011-2014</p>
</footer>
```

Add this `Jquery` script to all pages that you would like the `footer.html` in.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#footer').load('pathtofooter.html');
});
```

Add this `HTML` code, anywhere inside the `body` tag.

```
<div id='footer'></div>
```

Reference: [jquery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Any questions?

Comment: Yeah, I would like to know as well?

Comment: Well, I like it so I have voted it back up!

Comment: Wasn't me, I like the simplicity of this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode it in your script, and call it when the page is loaded :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var headerHtml = 'Whatever';
    var footerHtml = '<footer id="footer">\
                       <p>(c) Mattias Lindberg, 2011-2014</p>\
                      </footer>';

    $('#header-anchor').after(headerHtml);
    $('#footer-anchor').after(footerHtml);
});
```

Just use anchors where you want to put the header and footer.

Answer (score -2):

write it into a footer.html, pull it via ajax and append it to the body.

Comment: what's your problem, must an answer contain a full code solution for the op?!